# How to exclude a specific log4j default configuration file?

Tags: java, log4j

I have a project which depends on hadoop-core.

hadoop-core has its own log4j configuration.

The default log4j configuration is loaded in my project.

I want my project not to be affected by it.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want the hadoop-core provided log4j configuration to be the one used by log4j  you have to provide another configuration file that should be used.

You should have a look at the [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) manual. The section "[Default Initialization Procedure](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit)" describes how log4j will try to find the initialization file and explains possibilities to match a special configuration (e.g. by setting the system property `log4j.configuration`).